# What actually does Visual Studio do when it first starts up?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, ide, editor, visual-studio-2022

Recently I had to reinstall my Visual Studio 2022 and came across this step:

Visual Studio Start Up Screen

[image: 1]

It has been 30 minutes since it said 'This may take "a few" minutes'. This gets me wondering, what exactly does Visual Studio do when I first start them up? Doesn't it just move some files and setup configurations? How could it take so long?

I have been waiting for at least 30 minutes by now. I've seen people who had waited longer, some even had to wait for hours.

Comment: Weird, this normally is really a matter of minutes (at most). Could it be that your internet connection is somewhat flaky? Or your computer is a bit weak for VS2022?

Comment: My connection was working fine, I was searching over the internet for solution. What I ended up doing was simply killing Visual Studio and restart it. It works like a charm after that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after 3 hours I decided to kill the process using task manager. VS seems to work without any problems after a soft restart.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct, this step just move some files and setup configurations, but the time duration related to the workloads and components you first installed.

Also, as PMF mentioned, the current state of the hardware is also a possible reason.

If really long time, you can restart the computer and try again.

Any way, when you encounter this issue, just wait for it, and then it should installed successfully. If encounter issue between configuration, it will pop out error.

Comment: "Just wait for it" is not good advice.  The OP waited 3 hours, I waited 1 hour.  The program is hung; the process will never complete and never produce an error message.